# mips type R, I and J, RS, RT and RD fields length

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, machine-code, instruction-encoding

Is there any particular reason why RS, RT and RD fields have 5 bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIPS has `32` integer registers and `32` floating point registers and hence `5` bits are needed to represent each set of `32` registers.

The register letters `d`, `t`, and `s` are placeholders for (register) numbers or register names.

Read more on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS_assembly_language) and also [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121010181500/https://www.d.umn.edu/%7Egshute/spimsal/talref.html)

Comment: That is indeed the reason. The smallest storage space that is capable of holding every register value. The RS = source register, RD = destination register. (RT actually has a few purposes)

Comment: That should have said every register number not value. Typo.

Comment: Hi, the "University of Minnesota" url is inactive since years. This is the most recent archived page: http://web.archive.org/web/20121010181500/https://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/spimsal/talref.html

Comment: @ABO Thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect the link you provided.